# Нужно ли связующее слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В одном из предыдущих вопросом спросили насчет предложения "Лев был явно рассержен, что мы столь бесцеремонно нарушили его покой". По-моему, тут не хватает связующего слова "тем": "Лев был явно рассержен ТЕМ (или "из-за того"), что мы столь бесцеремонно нарушили его покой".
Или это не обязательно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Тем" желательно сохранять в книжной и в письменной речи вообще. При передаче устной речи, в стихах, при возвышенном стиле это совершенно не обязательно.

Прости, небесное созданье, 
Что я нарушил твой покой, 
Прости, но страстного 
Не отвергай признанья, 
Не отвергай с тоской! 
(Ариозо Германа)

Здесь, правда, опущено не "тем", а "за то" (другой падеж), но суть не меняется.

Answer (score 4):

Вы правы, гораздо лучше было бы употребить в главной части соотносительное слово ТЕМ: **"Лев был явно рассержен ТЕМ, что мы столь бесцеремонно нарушили его покой"**. Слово РАССЕРЖЕН по форме - краткое причастие, по сути - прилагательное. 
"***Не допускают изъяснительной части без соотносительных слов и некоторые прилагательные: Он уже был давно известен тем, что в другом городе и в другой труппе, играя в «Принцессе Грёзе» зеленого рыцаря, он упал и покатился в своих жестяных латах к рампе, громыхая, как огромный самовар (Купр.).***"(http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-045.htm)

Вариант предложения без соотносительного слова явно проигрывает.

Comment: Ссылка не открывается. Хотелось бы почитать. потому что возникают некоторые сомнения. Например, разве неверным будет "уверен, что..."

Comment: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-045.htm
Это Валгина "Синтаксис современного русского языка".

Comment: Спасибо! Хорошо бы (Валгиной) проиллюстрировать выражение "некоторые прилагательные" не одним примером.